# unfamiliar function declaration in c

Tags: c, gcc

I was looking into SslSplit [code](https://github.com/droe/sslsplit). And I faced some unfamiliar, strange function declarations in `opts.h` file. Definition of those functions are quite straightforward but I could use some help about declarations. Here it is:

**opts.h:**

```
char *proxyspec_str(proxyspec_t *) NONNULL(1) MALLOC;
void opts_set_crl(opts_t *, const char *) NONNULL(1,2);
```

**opts.c:**

```
void
opts_set_crl(opts_t *opts, const char *optarg)
{
    if (opts->crlurl)
        free(opts->crlurl);
    opts->crlurl = strdup(optarg);
    log_dbg_printf("CRL: %s\n", opts->crlurl);
}

char *
proxyspec_str(proxyspec_t *spec)
{
    char *s;
    char *lhbuf, *lpbuf;
    char *cbuf = NULL;

    // Some code..

    return s;
}
```

**attrib.h:**

```
#define WUNRES          __attribute__((warn_unused_result))
#define MALLOC          __attribute__((malloc)) WUNRES
#define NONNULL(...)    __attribute__((nonnull(__VA_ARGS__)))
```

My question is, what are the meanings of NONNULL and MALLOC at the end of the function declarations?

Comment: Well, just search the documentation of GCC: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html

Comment: They're preprocessor symbols. Do you know what preprocessor symbols are? If not, please consider reading a book, as most books cover the preprocessor... and C shouldn't be learnt without some kind of guidance.

Comment: @autistic any particular motivation on removing the C tag from this question?

Comment: @sidyll I added it back

Comment: @sidyll As the tag wiki says, "This tag should be used with general questions concerning the C language, as defined in the ISO 9899 standard (the latest version, 9899:2018, unless otherwise specified—also tag version-specific requests with c99, c89, etc)."... this question uses gcc-specific extensions (and asks specifically about them), thus this question is off-topic for C and on-topic for gcc.

Comment: @autistic The question is clearly about C to my eyes. Function attributes are also not exclusively GCC specific, other compilers feature them. Just because it's not in the language standard, doesn't mean it has nothing to do with the language itself. Moreover, the question targets a C code the questioner didn't understand. Anyway, you're welcome to bring this discussion to [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com) to check this possibility of interpretation. I'd be happy to correct myself in case I interpreted it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you pointed out yourself, `NONNULL` and `MALLOC` are just
macros. Their replacement  starts with `__attribute__` which
is a  compiler extension keyword, used  to define attributes
in a function.

The `__VA_ARGS__` is the replacement for the variable number
of arguments in  a macro (declared with the  `...`). So this
declaration:

```
void opts_set_crl(opts_t *, const char *) NONNULL(1,2);
```

Is transformed by the preprocessor (before the compiler sees
it) into:

```
void opts_set_crl(opts_t *, const char *) __attribute__((nonnull(1,2)));
```

What  this  effectively does  is  preventing  the first  and
second  parameters  of  being   `NULL`.  If  you  check  the
documentation of  a compiler which supports  this extension,
such as  [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) or [clang](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#id12)  you will find  the complete
description.

The other attribute, `malloc`, from the [GNU manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes):

> This tells the compiler that a function is malloc-like, i.e., that the
>   pointer P returned by the function cannot alias any other pointer
>   valid when the function returns, and moreover no pointers to valid
>   objects occur in any storage addressed by P.
>
> Using this attribute can improve optimization. Functions like malloc
>   and calloc have this property because they return a pointer to
>   uninitialized or zeroed-out storage. However, functions like realloc
>   do not have this property, as they can return a pointer to storage
>   containing pointers.

Comment: "the memory has undefined content. ... Standard functions with this property include malloc and calloc" - wait, what? The content of the memory returned by `calloc` is completely defined. There has to be a doc error here.

Comment: Looks like [later docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes) say something different (and more sensible): "This tells the compiler that a function is malloc-like, i.e., that the pointer P returned by the function cannot alias any other pointer valid when the function returns, and moreover no pointers to valid objects occur in any storage addressed by P."

Comment: @user2357112 Thank you for noticing this and updating it. I grabbed the first documentation search result without realizing it was so outdated.

Comment: I double-checked to see [C17](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf)/annex J.5 (common extensions) doesn't even seem to make a mention... so it doesn't even seem to be recognised as a common extension... I think there are probably only two implementations that support this...

Comment: As the author of the code in question I may just add to this fine answer that I introduced the macros so that the `__attribute__` decorators can be removed on compilers that do not support them. Also, I find the `__attribute__` syntax to be unreadable and hard to type.